# Style input font-weight bold?

Tags: css

I have the following CSS and HTML. All of the styles are applied apart from the font-weight bold. Is it possible to style an input in this way?

```
<span>
  <input type="submit">
</span>

span input {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: [not sure what issue you're having, it looks bold to me](http://jsfiddle.net/7n7Re/).

Comment: Works OK for me, are you sure there isn't another style overriding it?

Comment: Try: "font-weight:600;" , works in all browsers include ie 7 and 8. ie7 dont support "bold" prop in complex context of buttons but works with 600.

Comment: Keep in mind that input text fields use their own `font-family`, so many times your code works, but it's not the same font so it looks different. Try specifying `font-family` on the input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a style code that should work.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.inputClass{
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post.php" action="POST">
<input id="input" class="inputClass">
</form>
</body>
```

This will work instead of the original code since it is enclosed in `<style>` tags.

Let me know if that works for you or that is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Missing a bracket after font-weight.

Comment: This should work just a the original code should work. The question will not help future visitors unless it will be clarified what prevented the original code from working, such as a style sheet that was not disclosed.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I have edited.

Comment: If the issue is really that the CSS code was inserted in the midst of HTML content and not in a `style` element or an external style sheet, then it was an unbelievably trivial issue. Besides, then it was irrelevant to modify the CSS code at all.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I know, if you looked at my post I added a note to that.